# Would DHCP client renew after detecting link changed

Tags: dhcp, dhclient

I did below experiment with some devices.

1. prepare a DHCP server
2. prepare another device with DHCP client (`dhclient` was used)
3. client got its IP
4. I tried to link down and link up of client, and checked with `ethtool`

After link got up, `dhclient` didn't do anything.

I thought client should've renewed when detecting link changed.

What if I put this device to different network?

Comment: you answered your own question in the title ... question two depends on whether the different network contains a DHCP server